# Почему MODx выводит кракозябры?

Tags: php, mysql, modx

Использую для сайта движок MODx REVO. Локально всё работает, а на сервере выводит так:

УЧРЕЖДЕН�?Е ВЫСШЕГО ОБРАЗОВАН�?Я

Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в управление хостингом и установите кодировку подключения utf-8 для сайта. Либо в файле .htaccess напишите

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Затем зайдите в управление базой данных и для всех таблиц измените `collation на utf8_general_ci`.
Затем в файле `core/config/config.inc.php` убедитесь, что написано

```
$database_connection_charset = 'utf8';
$database_dsn = 'mysql:*************************charset=utf8';
```

После этого очистите кеш сайта (можно удалением папки core/cache)

Comment: Спасибо, работает!